# В `ListView` при скролинге не получается сохранить измененные шрифт и заливку цветом элементов списка

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursoradaper

В зоне видимости экрана эмулятора и реального устройства строчки списка меняют свой вид при клике. Но при скролле вверх-вниз  за границы экрана – та же строчка теряет форматирование.

Список заливается из `SQLite BD`.

Использую переопределенный `SimpleCursorAdapter` для изменения `backgroundColor` и `шрифта`  строчки списка.

`item` получает определенное форматирование в зависимости от отметки о "чекнутости" из базы.

```
 private class MySCA implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

        int listCheckInfo = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("colored"));

        TextView tv = (TextView) view;

        switch (listCheckInfo) {
            case 1:
                tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCheckedText));
                view.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.colorCheckedItem));
                return false;

            case 0:
                tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOfText));
                view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOfItem));
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

А так произвожу сам процес изменения форматирования `item` при клике на нем с занесением "чекнутости" в базу:

```
   public void toCheckProd(long id, View v, TextView tv, int check) {

    if (check == 0) {

        tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCheckedText));
        v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCheckedItem));
        dbPL.upDateCheck(id, 1);

    } else if (check == 1) {

        tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOfText));
        v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOfItem));
        dbPL.upDateCheck(id, 0);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что не могу найти способ как реализовать сохранение  форматирования строки списка.
В интернете нахожу примеры для `checkBox`.

Пытался делать тот же список, но с `checkBox` -  отказался, так как не такой функционал нужен.

Пробовал  закастомить что-то подобное `setOnCheckedChangeListener`  но переделать под `textView` так и не получилось.

Гдето на РУ.СО находил похожий на мой вопрос, но там автору не ответили.

Весь код длинный, потому залил на гитхаб.

https://github.com/vmarch/ViewColorChanger.git

Comment: Посмотри пример https://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/ Думаю тебе необходимо хранить №Измененной строки, и в методе 'GetView()' проверять и формировать разметку

Comment: Метод `setViewValue` должен возвращать `true`, если вы хотите чтобы ваш биндинг не игнорировался адаптером.

Comment: Если я правильно понял Вы заносите "чекнутость" item'а в базу, но не обновляете курсор и поэтому в биндере получаете старое значение.

Comment: @eugeneek , пробовал возвращать `true` , но не помогает. А возвращая  `true` в конце `case` приводит к тому что еще и текст не заливается в `item`. Реализация заполнения списка переходит к собственному биндеру `SimpleCursorAdapter`.  А для того чтобы добраться к нему - нужно заюзать `getView()`, как и предложил santavital.

Comment: @santavital на момент когда эту затею решил реализовать - попадались как раз реализации через  `ArrayAdapter`. Так как делал через БД то пришел к `setViewValue()` из `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`. А написав вроде рабочую реализацию уже жалко было откатиться.

Comment: @woesss оформите Ваш комент как ответ, действительно, при обновлении курсора все работает как задумано было.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После записи в базу необходимо обновить курсор, чтобы адаптер "увидел" изменения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ваш ответ кодом.