# Как работает ListView?

Tags: android, listview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Почему `ListView` повторяет позиции?

Например: я закрашиваю звезду на 4-й позиции и когда она исчезает после листания верх то снизу выходит другой `item` с позицией 10, но закрашенной почему-то .... а я не закрашивал 10-й `item` , я красил 4-й `item` ....

Comment: Как исправить ,, ????

Answer (score 5):

При создании нового айтема (`view`) списка адаптер для ускорения работы использует уже созданную ранее разметку для айтема, который вышел из зоны видимости экрана.

Принцип таков, что Вам нужно в адаптер при заполнении каждого айтема передавать так же информацию о том, какой айтем был закрашен, а какой нет.

Если элементы айтема (у Вас это звезды) это чекбоксы - то вам нужно сохранять информацию о том в каком айтеме был нажат чекбокс. Стоит посмотреть в сторону `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

Если Ваши звезды это виджеты не являющийся чекбоксами, то нужно информацию о покрашеном айтеме сохранить, например в каком-то массиве, или `SharedPreferences` или `БД`. Потом при листании вытаскивать сохраненную информацию об айтеме который должен появиться в зоне видимости и передавать в адаптер информацию о том закрашен или нет этот элемент.

Как вариант можете посмотреть мой пример заливки цветом айтемомов списка. Там я хранил информацию в `БД`, заливал `ListView` с помощью `SimpleCursorAdapter`, а его переопределенный  `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` использовал для изменения шрифта и цвета айтема при клике на `view`.

[В `ListView` при скролинге не получается сохранить измененные шрифт и заливку цветом элементов списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688319/?sgp=2)

Answer (score 3):

Просто запомните. Программная установка чего-либо должна выполняться как-будто айтем не тронутый. Другими словами вам надо обрабатывать оба случая

Например, вместо

```
if(favorite){
    star.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Надо писать

```
if(favorite){
    star.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE):
}
else{
    star.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Это должно у вас просто запомниться.

И, кстати, переходите на `RecyclerView`